# AutoFac - Resolve But Pass Specific Constructor Value

Tags: autofac

I need to scan an assembly and, for each type that implements some interface (let's say IFoo) I need to register it with the container for later resolution. Say I have an IFoo class that takes 2 parameters in an assembly

```
public class MyFooA : IFoo
{
   public MyFoo(SomeRandomObject o, ILogger logger)
   {
   }
}
```

I have already registered ILogger with the container, and I need to resolve IFoo from it, but at resolution, I need to provide SomeRandomObject o (this can't be in the container). I should only have one implementation for the IFoo so I don't need to specifically name it (at least not yet)

Also note that the implementation of IFoo is found via reflection and the number/type of parameters it has is unknown until it's found.

How do I register and resolve these?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow exactly, but by "number/type of parameters it has is unknown until it's found", you mean the constructor can be something like : public MyFoo(SomeRandomObject o, OtherRandomObject2 o2, YetOtherRandomObject2 o3, ILogger logger) ? and those are not always registered in the container?

Comment: [Have you read the docs?](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/parameters.html)